# Salesforce login with third-party open id connect - no_openid_response

Tags: salesforce, openid-connect

I'm trying to use my third-party app to sign-in in a Salesforce community. I've registered the client, created the auth. provider and so on, but when I test the initialization URL it gives me the following error:

```
ErrorCode=No_Openid_Response&ErrorDescription=No+response
```

Can anyone help me with this? I have no idea what's missing or where (salesforce or on the auth. server). Thank you

Comment: Can you add some more details on this ? what sort of auth server are you using ? And do you get this response after login ?

Comment: I've solved this one, it was an error on the auth server. But now I have a different error:
Missing_Value: Could not find unique third-party identifier

When I try the SSO it shows me that message. The test-only URL is working, but the sign on is not because of this. Have you had this problem?

Comment: @maj i am getting the same 'no_openid_response' error. what did you do to fix it on the auth server? I'm using google auth provider.