# SalesForce OpenID Issue "ErrorCode=No_Openid_Response&ErrorDescription=Bad+response"

Tags: authentication, oauth, salesforce, openid-connect, openid

I posted this in the SalesForce developers forum but so far I have not got any answer. I hope some of you could give me an insight.

I am trying to setup OpenID Connect in SalesForce using a 3rd party as idP. I am able to be redirected to the iDP, introduce my credentials, but in the moment of going back to SalesForce I got the error the next browser string error: https://personal156-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=No_Openid_Response&ErrorDescription=Bad+response&ProviderId=0SO4x0000004PmJ

I added the callback URL in the IdP and enabled the scopes "openid and profile", note that I do not have "email" in the default scope field. My IdP includes the email information inside of the scope "profile". So I was wondering if the email field is a must in the scope and that's why probably I am getting the error previously described.

Below my configuration

[SalesForce Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g6uv.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps this Stackoverflow clues? [Salesforce login with third-party open id connect - no_openid_response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765470/salesforce-login-with-third-party-open-id-connect-no-openid-response) or this one? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202308/openid-connect-bad-response

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue following this recommendation: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202308/openid-connect-bad-response

Normally the userinfo comes as signed JWT, you should disable the sign and get the response as JSON (not JWT/JWA).

Surprisingly as far as I know SalesForce does not support userinfo response signed.

I hope this helps to somebody.

thank you,